# What would be a good way to pivot a Snowpark DataFrame around a column?

Tags: sql, dataframe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've read the Snowpark (Python) docs and there is a **pivot** function for DataFrames, but that's not quite what I'm looking for. What I want is to be able to pivot a DataFrame around a column and have, for each distinct value of this column, a column that is an array of all rows which have this value. Let's say I have this DataFrame:

```
| a    | b              | c                      |
| ---- | -------------- | ---------------------- |
| 1    | X              | { "prop": 9 }          |
| 2    | Y              | { "prop": 10 }         |
| 3    | Z              | { "prop": 10 }         |
| 4    | Z              | { "prop": 11 }         |
| 5    | X              | { "prop": 9 }          |
```

Let's say I want to pivot the DataFrame around "c.prop", I'm looking for the transformation I need to do to obtain this DataFrame:

```
| c.prop    | rows                       
| --------- | ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| 9         | [{ "a": 1, "b": "X" c: { "prop": 9 }}, { "a": 5, "b": "X" c: { "prop": 9 }}]         |
| 10        | [{ "a": 2, "b": "Y" c: { "prop": 10 }}, { "a": 3, "b": "Z" c: { "prop": 10 }}]       |
| 11        | [{ "a": 4, "b": "Z" c: { "prop": 11 }}]                                            |
```

Right now, the closest I have to a solution is "flattening" the dataframe and then, for each distinct value of the column I want to pivot against, filter the original DataFrame to keep only the rows where the column has this specific value.

Comment: Do you want an answer in SQL or what language? If you show us what you have tried so far, that would be a great help

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Ideally Snowpark (Python), less ideally Snowflake SQL. I've tried a bunch of stuff, which I think is best not to include in the question to avoid cluttering it. I said I read the docs, I've provided an example with an "input" DataFrame and an output "DataFrame", I'm not sure including my failed attempts would help someone answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you the answer in SQL, since it's easy for me to reproduce the sample scenario and solve it just with a `group by` and an `object_construct(*)`. Please note that this is not technically "a pivot", but exactly the results you are asking for:

```sql
with data_raw(x, a, b, c) as (
    select split(value, '|') x, x[1]::int, trim(x[2]::string), parse_json(x[3])
    from table(split_to_table(
    $$| 1    | X              | { "prop": 9 }          |
    | 2    | Y              | { "prop": 10 }         |
    | 3    | Z              | { "prop": 10 }         |
    | 4    | Z              | { "prop": 11 }         |
    | 5    | X              | { "prop": 9 }          |$$, '\n'))
), data as (
    select * exclude(x)
    from data_raw
)

select "c.prop", array_agg(o) "rows"
from (
    select c:prop "c.prop", object_construct(*) o
    from data
)
group by 1
order by 1
```

[image]

(this should be straightforward to implement with dataframes)

Comment: Thank you very much :) I can always call SQL statements from Snowpark, so that suits my need perfectly